# Get access to checked item and position outside setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, position, checked

I have a list view with single selection mode and would like to get access the position outside the setOnItemClickListener event

As of now I can access its position as shown below

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            //btnNxt.setEnabled(true);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NewActivity.class);
            // Pass a single position
            i.putExtra("position", position);
            // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
            startActivity(i);

        }
});
```

Now I would like to know how do I access the selected position outside(ie..on button click event).

```
btnNxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
            //Here I need to get the position and selected item
                }
});
```

Listview.xml

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#3366CC"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

ItemDetails.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.abc.widget.CheckableRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/sampleimg"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemname"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemdesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/carname"
         android:focusable="false"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemprice" 
        android:textSize="19sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#003399" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardesc"/>

   <com.example.abc.widget.InertCheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox" />
</RelativeLayout>
</com.example.abc.widget.CheckableRelativeLayout>
```

OrElse how do I check If any listview item is checked or not on button click ?

EDIT:

This is the way I'm trying to access the position from button click

```
btnNxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {              
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            myposition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
```

Comment: you can use a sparsebooleanarray to get checked items as i have shown yesterday

Comment: @Rqaghunandan-As you previously stated I have used using sparsebooleanarray as described in my previous solution but It gives me null in my case.

Comment: it won't if you have coded properly

Comment: Actually mine is not a multi choice its a single choice so I think its useless in using sparsebooleanarray

Comment: if you think its useless well i can't comment any further good luck

Comment: I am not saying that your suggestion is useless but waiting for a better answer who can give me a better suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make a member variable (declare it outside of a method like before `onCreate()` and use that.

```
public class ...
{
    int pos;

    // onCreate() and such



     final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
     lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            pos = position;   // initialize it

          ...
        }
});
```

then use `pos` inside your `onClick()` or wherever you need to in the `Activity`.

If I completely missed something in your question then please explain.

Comment: i was just thinking if user does not click on list item and then clicks on button then pos won't get the position

Comment: @Raghunandan good point! But he has `btnNext.setEnabled(true)` commented out so I figured he would uncomment that line. I suppose I should have mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: @Raghunandan-If the item was selected and click on buton also the position returns null..

Comment: @codeMagic-yes I have tried the same it returns null..If it's inside the itemclick event then it returns the position

Comment: Using my code `pos` returns `null`? I'm not sure how. Is this all in the same `Activity`?

Comment: Is the `onClick()` for the `Button` in the same `Activity` as your `ListView`? If not then you need to show how you are trying to access it.

Comment: @coder when you click on list item you get the position. pos get the postion. then you click on the button you can do what you want with pos. Are you clicking button before pos is initialized with the position?

Comment: @codeMagic-Updated with your answer how I'm trying to use it inside button click

Comment: @Raghunandan- I think something is messing aroud with my code can you say me how do I check If the listview item is checked or not inside button click..Is it the same as you said above using sparsebooleanarray or any other way to check?

Comment: If `myPosition` is an `int` then it won't work in a `Toast`. Look at [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)). It would be looking for a `resource id`. You will need to change it to a `String`.

Comment: See our first comments on this answer. You can disable the `Button` and then enable it when an item is selected. You have the code there but commented out so I thought you would understand that.

Comment: @CodeMagic-That was the problem..Got it rectified..Thanks for your help.Converting it to string finally worked out.

Comment: @coder i have used SparseBoolean array from Romain Guy solution @ https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M